# How to disambiguate a second version of an installation from command-line?

Tags: software-installation, path, executable

I installed a tool called herd (http://diy.inria.fr/herd/). The original version of this I think is in the global path so I can call it from anywhere by writing `herd7`. Now I also have a second installation which I compiled myself. It is in a different directory. I don't know how to call that second one specifically. I think it's something to do with writing out the whole path but I'm not even sure how to find out what the path is and when I guessed it and tried

`./herd --help`

it just told me `Is a directory`. So, yeah, how do I call the actual tool?

I'm new to using linux and command-line so I know I'm probably using the wrong jargon.

Edit:

Well I found that there was a directory called `_build` with `default` inside it which itself had a folder `herd` inside it which had inside it `herd.exe`. Then running `./herd.exe --help` from within that folder worked (and `./herd --help` did not). But still, do I need to specify the `.exe`? Shouldn't it have a command-line usage `herd7` like the original installation?

Comment: The `.exe` is there because the way you compiled that tool, the executable file is called `herd.exe`, not `herd`: There's no magic here. You're actually executing files, which must be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of convention.  I'll use the `gcc` compiler as an example to explain things.

Typing `which gcc` in Redhat 8 results in `/usr/bin/gcc`.  Doing `gcc --version` results in `version 4.8.5` which is the default installed version.

If I want to download and install a later version of `gcc` such as version 11.4, I tell it in its config that the install directory of it will explicitly be `/usr/local/gcc-11.4`.  This way is does not overwrite the existing gcc-4.8.5 under `/usr/bin`.  And for when I want to run gcc-11.4 then I can either explicitly do `/usr/local/gcc-11.4/bin/gcc` or modify the `PATH` (and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) environment variables to put `/usr/local/gcc-11.4/bin` and `/usr/local/gcc-11.4/lib` into them {respectively} before `/usr/bin` within `PATH`, so that when I type just `gcc` it results in using the 11.4 version not the 4.8.5 version.  Doing a `echo $PATH` will show that contents, and whichever folder an executable is first found in is what is used.

You can install your newer `herd` version under `/usr/local` or under `/opt` or anywhere else.  Manually tacking on the version number to the folder name goes a long way in managing things when you forget what's what however many days (or hours) later.

You can update `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` multiple ways, either per user via your `/home/<account>/.bashrc` or globally for all users under `/etc/profile.d/<some_name>.sh` or by using `modules`.   Overall, it's not complicated it's just a matter of understanding the digital organization and housekeeping of it.

> How to disambiguate a second version on the command-line ?

that all happens with the order of folder listing under the `PATH` environment variable, and also the listing in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Whichever folder your executable, or supporting library file, is found in first, is what is used.  So you reorder those two environment variables, either manually (if it's just for you), or in a work environment with many users and many software versions that can conflict with each other then use `modules`... *The Modules package is a tool that simplifies shell initialization and lets users easily modify their environment during a session using modulefiles.*  https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/